# Refining to show payments 3 months or more beyond retirement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure if this is possible but I need to refine this query so that it will only show those payments (p.PAY_DT) that are equal to or greater then 3 months or more after the retire date (e.RETIRE_DT).

```
SELECT p.*
FROM [employeedb].[dbo].[employees] e JOIN
 [paydatabase].[dbo].[PAY_DT] p
 ON p.EMPY_ID = e.EMPY_ID AND
    p.PAY_DT >= e.RETIRE_DT;
 WHERE p.STATUS='Retired'
```

Comment: I'm confused.  If the retire date is in `employee`s, what is `status`?  And why is it in `pay_dt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `dateadd`

```
SELECT p.*
FROM [employeedb].[dbo].[employees] e
JOIN [paydatabase].[dbo].[PAY_DT] p ON p.EMPY_ID = e.EMPY_ID
WHERE p.STATUS='Retired' and p.PAY_DT >= DATEADD(mm,3,e.RETIRE_DT)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM [employeedb].[dbo].[employees] e JOIN
 [paydatabase].[dbo].[PAY_DT] p
 ON p.EMPY_ID = e.EMPY_ID AND
    p.PAY_DT >= e.RETIRE_DT;
 WHERE p.STATUS='Retired' and p.PAY_DT>=DATEADD(month,3,e.RETIRE_DT)
```